# How do i create a more efficient structured/rec array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have created a rec array in numpy like this. Is this the most efficient way to create this?

```
my_array = np.array([(np.datetime64('1970-01-01'),
               np.array([np.zeros(12), np.zeros(12)], dtype='float64'),
               np.array([np.zeros(12), np.zeros(12)], dtype='uint64'),
               np.array([np.zeros(12), np.zeros(12)], dtype='uint64'),
               np.array([np.empty(12, dtype='<M8[us]'),
                         np.empty(12, dtype='<M8[us]')]),
               np.array([np.empty(12), np.empty(12)], dtype='object'),
               np.array([np.empty(1, dtype='uint64'),
                         np.empty(1, dtype='uint64')]))],
               dtype=[('index', 'datetime64[us]'), ('price', 'object'), ('quantity', 'object'),
                      ('id', 'object'), ('timestamp', 'object'), ('customer', 'object'),
                      ('action', 'object')])
```

How do i access all elements in action and retrieve the first of it. For example action is as follows but i am unable to retrieve the second element from each of the arrays.

```
[[array([[1],
   [0]], dtype=uint64)]
 [array([[1],
   [0]], dtype=uint64)]
 [array([[1],
   [1]], dtype=uint64)]
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more that which elements do you want to access?

Comment: what's `my_array.shape`?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your array:

```
In [302]: my_array.shape                                                                               
Out[302]: (1,)
In [303]: my_array['action']                                                                           
Out[303]: 
array([array([[0],
       [0]], dtype=uint64)], dtype=object)
In [304]: my_array['action'].shape                                                                     
Out[304]: (1,)
In [305]: my_array['action'][0]                                                                        
Out[305]: 
array([[0],
       [0]], dtype=uint64)
```

To get at the (2,1) array you have to pick the 'action' field, and the first (only) element of the array.

```
In [306]: my_array.dtype                                                                               
Out[306]: dtype([('index', '<M8[us]'), ('price', 'O'), ('quantity', 'O'), ('id', 'O'), ('timestamp', 'O'), ('customer', 'O'), ('action', 'O')])
```

By specifying 'O' dtype you've added a referencing layer.  It gives added flexibility.

You use this pattern a lot:

```
In [313]: np.array([np.zeros(12), np.zeros(12)], dtype='float64')                                      
Out[313]: 
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
In [314]: _.shape                                                                                      
Out[314]: (2, 12)
In [315]: np.zeros((2,12),dtype='float64')                                                             
Out[315]: 
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```